# @njit(parallel=True) making code run slower on new laptop

Tags: python, nvidia, numba

I've recently gotten a new laptop, with better performance (in theory) but the same code I wrote on my old laptop, where i use `@njit(parallel=True)` to speed up functions using numpy and loops is now causing the code to run much slower.

Any ideas?

I have a dell precision, intel i7 with NVIDIA GPU. I feel like i've not installed or set-up something correctly but am a bit lost.

I've installed cudatoolkit, as well as the latest numba. I've set `CUDA_HOME` to where the cudatoolkit is installed.

An example of some of the functions I am using:

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def find_nearest(array, value):
    """ Given an array and a value, this function will find the index position inside the array that matches closest to the value
    """
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

@njit(parallel=True)
def rms(y):
    """ calculates the root mean square of an array 
    """
    rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(y**2))
    return rms

@njit(parallel=True)
def dc_normalize(sig_array):
    """Removes DC and normalizes to -1, 1 range
    """
    sig_array_norm = np.asarray(sig_array.copy())
    sig_array_norm -= sig_array_norm.mean()
    sig_array_norm /= np.absolute(sig_array_norm).max() + 1e-10
    return sig_array_norm

@njit(parallel=True)
def energy(frame):
    """Computes signal energy 
    """
    return np.sum(frame ** 2) / np.float64(len(frame))
```

Another example:

```py
start = datetime.now()

@njit(parallel=True)
def rms(y):
    """ calculates the root mean square of an array 
    """
    rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(y**2))
    return rms

x = np.random.rand(100000)
result = rms(x)

print('with @njit:', datetime.now()-start)

start = datetime.now()

def rms(y):
    """ calculates the root mean square of an array 
    """
    rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(y**2))
    return rms

x = np.random.rand(100000)
result = rms(x)

print('without @njit:', datetime.now()-start)
```

output:

```
with @njit: 0:00:00.253571
without @njit: 0:00:00.004011
```

Comment: So did you check the memory size and performance? Same for the SD ?

Comment: yeah i've got more memory, more RAM, better core processor etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Included some functions i am using above

Comment: First of all, Numba do not run things on your GPU automatically. You need to specify it, send data to GPUs etc. This is a common belief. Based on this, the GPU information are useless since your GPU is not used. When it comes to the CPU, the performance is dependent to the target task so an old CPU can be faster than a new one for some specific tasks. Please provide the specific *reference* of the CPU (eg. i5-9600KF). "i7" gives almost no information about performance : an i7-4500u will be slow compare to an i5-10600k for most task. The DRAM speed (missing) also matter a lot for Numpy tasks.

Comment: Note that Numba compile functions lazily so you should not take this time into account in your benchmark (which will be biased otherwise). Details like the size of the array and their type matters a lot. Such information are missing. The allocator also matters for small arrays, that is, the libc used and possibly even its version. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1370P   1.90 GHz

Comment: Another example above